# Throw nested exception through java Throwable

Tags: java, throw, throwable

I trying to throw inner exception in another exception through java `Throwable` but IDE told my that you must surround it with `try/cath`, What should I do to avoid from this problem?

```
    try
    {
        //Some code
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Throwable cause = new Throwable();
        cause.initCause(e);
        throw cause.getCause();
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand how checked exceptions work.

Comment: I think your code in `catch` does nothing ... `throw e` would do the same ...

Comment: @kkonrad: Getting rid of it entirely would also do the same.  He needs to understand how checked exceptions work.

Comment: clearly. I though that maybe he would like to print that something happened and than re-throw this. Still - lack of knowledge about exceptions in java ...

Comment: It's not at all clear what the OP is trying to do, but it does look like omitting the `try`/`catch` entirely would have the same effect.

Comment: He says it clearly: "I trying to throw inner exception in another exception ..." so I don't think skipping `try/catch` is solution for him ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method signature to this:

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException
{   
    //some code
}
```

Have a look at [this site](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/carcassi/archive/2009/09/25/simple-guide-checked-exceptions) for some useful information on checked exceptions and a little on the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Declare `IOException` as a checked exception in your function's signature.